# Tag synonym: [hr] and [human-resources]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

It looks to me that the [hr](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hr) is a synonym of [human-resources](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/human-resources).

I don't see any questions which are tagged with [hr](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hr) in a different way then [human-resources](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/human-resources).

I also notice that half the question asked with this tag [hr](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hr) have been asked in the last few weeks.

So are the two tags synonymous?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, and now the system knows they are synonyms too. Nice catch! Thanks.